# How to get indexpath from row index Swift

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, indexpath

I am loading an array to `UIcollectionview`(later will add other data) . I want to select collection view item randomly as:

```
var indexpath = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(items.count)-1) 

self.collectionview.selectitem(at: **indexpath**, animated:true ,scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPosition)
```

Here it’s giving me error at bold position saying:

> cannot convert value of type Int to expected argument type 'IndexPath?

I can understand this exception as `indexpath` is different in swift from collection data index(array index). But I am unable to find any method that can convert item index to indexpath or anyother way.

I am newer to iOS so might be not good at searching correct keywords for such issue. It will be a great favour from you all for any other method to this requirement.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To create an `IndexPath` in swift 3 for `UICollectionView`

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
```

Comment: can you please the swift 4 version?

Comment: This is valid for `UICollectionView` in swift 4.

Comment: I have a loop "for" I make it like this `for var i in 0..<self.myDatasource.count { let indexPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0) 
}` but the application crash at this line because of `nil`

Answer (score 4):

You can use it

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 Latest

```
self.table.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.1. Here I created function to get NSIndexPath. Just pass your UIView(UIButton,UITextField etc) and UICollectionView object to get NSIndexPath.

```
func getIndexPathFor(view: UIView, collectionView: UICollectionView) -> NSIndexPath? {

        let point = collectionView.convert(view.bounds.origin, from: view)
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point)
        return indexPath as NSIndexPath?
    }
```